# How can I run a query with parameters from Visio VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, visio

I've been using the DataRecordsets.Add method to pull from my database, but when I try that on a query with parameters I get an error: "Unable to connect to the data." How can I pass the parameters to the query?